# Create an array from checkbox

Tags: php

I tried in many ways to create an array using this form,but i can't find any that work. I need also to convert the array in a string so I can add this in the database. This is the code
php

```
$Generea = isset($_POST['Genere']);
    $Genere = implode(";", $Generea);
```

html

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Genere*:</legend>
<input type = "checkbox" value="Action" Name="Genere[]"/>Action
<input type = "checkbox" value="Platform" Name="Genere[]"/>Platform
<input type = "checkbox" value="Shooter" Name="Genere[]"/>Shooter
<input type = "checkbox" value="Fighting" Name="Genere[]"/>Fighting
<input type = "checkbox" value="Beat 'em ups" Name="Genere[]"/>Beat 'em ups<BR>
<input type = "checkbox" value="Stealth" Name="Genere[]"/>Stealth
<input type = "checkbox" value="Survival" Name="Genere[]"/>Survival
<input type = "checkbox" value="Adventure" Name="Genere[]"/>Adventure
<input type = "checkbox" value="Avventura testuale" Name="Genere[]"/>Avventura testuale
<input type = "checkbox" value="Avventura grafica"/ Name="Genere[]"/>Avventura grafica<BR>
<input type = "checkbox" value="RPG" Name="Genere[]"/>RPG
<input type = "checkbox" value="MMO" Name="Genere[]"/>MMO
<input type = "checkbox" value="Strategy" Name="Genere[]"/>Strategy
<input type = "checkbox" value="Sandbox" Name="Genere[]"/>Sandbox
<input type = "checkbox" value="Simulation" Name="Genere[]"/>Simulation<BR>
<input type = "checkbox" value="Sport" Name="Genere[]"/>Sport
<input type = "checkbox" value="Racing" Name="Genere[]"/>Racing
<input type = "checkbox" value="Music" Name="Genere[]"/>Music
<input type = "checkbox" value="Party" Name="Genere[]"/>Party
<input type = "checkbox" value="Horror" Name="Genere[]"/>Horror
</fieldset>
```

As Form method i use POST

Comment: you need to add the code you're using for the database and why are you using `;` as a separator? That could pose problems, since it's considered as an "end of statement" character. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php --- and you should normalize your db.

Comment: check all checkboxes and click submit

Comment: `$Generea = isset($_POST['Genere']);` that won't work; it's assuming they are all set. Either check `if` it's set, or use a ternary. You also need to use a `foreach`. Question is unclear/too broad.

Comment: first line gives an `boolean` so the second can't do something with your value (like `implode`).

Comment: `Beat 'em ups` that alone is an sql injection if not treated correctly.

Comment: `$Genere = !empty( $_POST['Genere'] ) ? implode(";", $_POST['Genere'] ) : false;` - then test for `$genre` being false before any database insert??

Answer (score 0):

You should be imploding the `$_POST` variable, not the result of `isset()` (which is just `true` or `false`).

```
if (isset($_POST['Genere']) {
    $Genere = implode(';', $_POST['Genere']);
}
```